# Screen.blit doesnt work unless keydown

Tags: python, pygame, python-2.6

I'm starting out in python and pygame. so I have been introduced to screen.blit for showing pictures on the screen. however when I use screen.blit nothing will happen in my program unless I am moving my mouse or clicking a button. I have no idea why this happens, I have simplified an example with only a cat moving across the screen. Nothing happens unless I am pressing a button or moving my mouse. I am using python 2.6.6

```html
import pygame

pygame.init()
 
# Set the width and height of the screen [width, height]
size = (800, 600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

floor = pygame.image.load("floor.png").convert()
cat = pygame.image.load("cat.png").convert()

a=0
b=0

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # --- Main event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            done = True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop
  
    # --- Game logic should go here
 a+=1
 b+=1
    # --- Drawing code should go here
 
 # First, clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
 # above this, or they will be erased with this command.
 screen.blit(floor, [0,0])
 screen.blit(cat, [a,b])
 # --- Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
 pygame.display.flip()
  pygame.display.update()
    # --- Limit to 60 frames per second
 clock.tick(60)
 
# Close the window and quit.
# If you forget this line, the program will 'hang'
# on exit if running from IDLE.
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the screen.blip is inside the `for event in pygame.event.get():`

Correct the indentation and it will be fixed.

Try this:

```
while not done:
    # --- Main event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            done = True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

    # --- Game logic should go here
    a+=1
    b+=1
    # --- Drawing code should go here

    # First, clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
    # above this, or they will be erased with this command.
    screen.blit(floor, [0,0])
    screen.blit(cat, [a,b])
    # --- Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
    # --- Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: wow I feel silly now, although in my editor they appear to be on the same tabstop. interesting. i just moved the for loop to the bottom of the while loop.

Comment: Glad I could help. But maybe that happen because you are mixing tabs and spaces for indentations. Get a editor that converts from tabs to 4 spaces and you will not have this problem again. ;)

Comment: nah I use tab for spaces but I could use a better editor, could you recommend one? :)

Comment: I use PyCharm, but it's a bit overkill for that matter. There's Notepad++ which is pretty good too.